# building a MailChimp signup form, get a PHP parse error mystery

Tags: php, jquery, mailchimp

I'm working with the code I got from http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/
called "MCAPI Simple Subscribe Example code" -- the one with jQuery.

Locally, where the PHP version is 5.3.5, it works just fine. But when I deploy it to production, where the PHP version is which is 5.2.17, I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/myperf7/
>   public_html/inc/store-address.php on line 1

See it in action at http://myperfectbicycle.com/ -- as you can see,
this error is not just aesthetic. It prevents the form from collecting
the email address successfully.

Any idea what might be causing that? I can provide further phpinfo() details if needed -- just don't want to spam you all. Here are the contents of store-address.php:

```
    <?php

    function storeAddress(){

        // Validation
        if(!$_GET['email']){ return "No email address provided"; } 

        if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i", $_GET['email'])) {
            return "Email address is invalid"; 
        }

        require_once('MCAPI.class.php');
        // grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
        $api = new MCAPI('XXXXXXX');

        // grab your List's Unique Id by going to http://admin.mailchimp.com/lists/
        // Click the "settings" link for the list - the Unique Id is at the bottom of that page. 
        $list_id = "XXXXXXX";

        if($api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_GET['email'], '') === true) {
            // It worked!   
            return 'Success! Check your email to confirm sign up.';
        }else{
            // An error ocurred, return error message   
            return 'Error: ' . $api->errorMessage;
        }

    }

    // If being called via ajax, autorun the function
    if(isset($_GET['ajax'])){ echo storeAddress(); }

    ?>
```

What portion of this code wouldn't work properly in PHP version 5.2? Hmmm...

In the comments somebody asked how the store-address.php file being included; here is it, from my index.php page:

```
    <form id="signup" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
        <input type="text" value="" name="email" class="email" id="email" placeholder="email address" required="required" />
        <div class="clear">
            <input type="submit" value="Notify me" name="subscribe" class="button"/>
        </div>
        <span id="response"><?php require_once('inc/store-address.php'); if(isset($_GET['submit'])){ echo storeAddress(); } ?></span>
    </form>
```

Comment: Well check if you have the same error reporting configuration with your PHP 5.3 setup. You might see the same message there if.

Comment: By the way, my hosting provider InMotion will not allow me to upgrade to PHP version 5.3.... :( So I need to figure out how to get this code working in a 5.2 friendly way :)

Comment: Comment out the `require_once`. You should get a Fatal Error "Class MCAPI not found" or something. If so, there may be a syntax error in `MCAPI.class.php`. Not a full answer, just a step to debug.

Comment: @hakre PHP 5.2 locally has error_reporting at 32767. PHP 5.3 on live has error_reporting at 6135. Does that answer your point? I don't know what these mean...

Comment: How is the store_address file being included?

Comment: Error Reporting: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - Check for `display_errors` on the 5.3 setup as well. Enable it if it is your dev-box. Otherwise check the error_log.

Comment: @adlawson I tried that but there was no change on the front-end. Still I get a slightly different error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected **T_STRING** in.." rather than ** T_FUNCTION** -- does that help?

Comment: @Pekka it's being included in my index.php with this line: <? require_once('inc/store-address.php'); if(isset($_GET['submit'])){ echo storeAddress(); } ?>

Comment: @hakre `display_errors` is enabled on the 5.2 setup (live); when I disable it, the error message disappears but the form still does not function correctly. On the 5.3 setup (dev), `display_errors` is also enabled.

Comment: `<?` <- short open tag. Change it to `<?php` and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: @hakre Thanks but I tried that too, no change.

Comment: Is there any way to re-write the function so it works in PHP version 5.2?

Comment: This file cannot (just because **there is no function token on 1st line** as the error declares) throw such error. You have a error somewhere else

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code that would break it with 5.2, so I'd guess there's something wrong with your server.

Comment: It's not considered good etiquette to cross post on the SE network:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102984 Please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068

Comment: @Kev oh sorry! I am new here, I did not know. Will not happen again.

Comment: @NullUserException thanks for reviewing the code. If it's 5.2-safe, then I've got some more digging to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the error is on line 1, and looking on your site is says:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/myperf7/public_html/inc/store-address.php on line 1

I would suggest opening up your store-address.php and looking for any random strings, spaces, newlines, etc. on the first line of the file.  Also, it might be a good idea to have the `storeAddress()` response block on multiple lines.

```
<span id="response"><?php 
require_once('inc/store-address.php'); 
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){ 
    echo storeAddress(); 
} 

?></span>
```

The `require_once()` certainly should be on a separate line.

Comment: Thank you @CamelBlues but there's no randomness on the first line of store-address.php. I've even removed all "tab"s so it's only spaces between code. I checked that again and moved the response block on multiple lines like you suggested. But still, no good result. Still the error message on my site. :(

Comment: There WAS in fact randomness on the first line. In fact, the entire file was in one long single line! Stupid Netbeans IDE, saving my files into a single line when I didn't ask it to! I've changed that in my Netbeans config and all is well now. :)